# how can i use django.utils.safestring.py

Tags: python, django

```
from django.utils.safestring import *

print SafeString('\u3042')
print '\u3042'

\u3042
\u3042
```

who can give me a better example.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of [django.utils.safestring.SafeString](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/_modules/django/utils/safestring/) is a string which has already been vetted or escaped, so it contains no characters that could give HTML a parsing problem ('<', '>', '&').  See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping).